# Master web part for 'Get Form from' connection

Tags: web-part, infopath, connected-web-parts

My task is to develop webpart, which will act as master data webpart for child (standard) **Infopath Form Web part**. This Infopath form web part will connect  my web part with: **Get form from**... connection type.

Question: what must my web part implement to be able acting in such type of binding? Some interface... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect two custom web parts. To do this, [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms469765(v=office.14).aspx) will be a good start. If you want to connect a custom web part with a build in web part like **Infopath Form Web part**, then it would be bit complex. I did not see this yet. Hope other guys will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to connect web parts. My custom web part implements custom interface (for business specific bindings), implements IWebPartRow and IWebPartTable standard interfaces (for common bindings). Only thing I must do is rich it with possibility of "Get Form from" binding... And I am not able to find some relevant info , how to solve it.